# Shuffling data across rows in a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, random, randomized-algorithm

I want to update a table to have the data shuffled around. Let's say I have a table with 5 columns. column 1 is the primary key so that'll remain unchanged. columns 2 and 3 will be shuffled to different rows. columns 4 and 5 will also be shuffled but as pairs (they must be moved together).

How would I write the script for this? The primary key is a random unique identifier so it doesn't correlate with the row number.

Before:

| c1 | c2 | c3 | c4 | c5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
| 20 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 |
| 30 | 9 | 10 | 11 | 12 |
| 40 | 13 | 14 | 15 | 16 |

After:

| c1 | c2 | c3 | c4 | c5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 5 | 14 | 11 | 12 |
| 20 | 9 | 6 | 15 | 16 |
| 30 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
| 40 | 13 | 10 | 7 | 8 |

To provide an update on why I am doing this, this isn't a production database or anything. I'm shuffling the data around to anonymize the data for testing purposes, that's about it.

To provide additional details, say this is a people table. I might shuffle the address or phone number to anonymize the person.

Comment: Your design is broken if you find yourself having to do this sort of operation on a relational database.

Comment: `PRIMARY KEY` uniquely identify a row.  How can you shuffle columns in a row?  It does not make sense.

Answer (score 1):

If temporary tables are allowed:

- Create a temporary table that contains row_number based keys

  - One key acts as a secondary key
  - Other keys will consist secondary key values but sorted randomly

```
select *
     , sk = row_number() over (order by c1)
     , k1 = row_number() over (order by newid())
     , k2 = row_number() over (order by newid())
     , k3 = row_number() over (order by newid())
into #temp
from t
```

| c1 | c2 | c3 | c4 | c5 | sk | k1 | k2 | k3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 1 | 4 | 3 | 1 |
| 20 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 2 |
| 30 | 9 | 10 | 11 | 12 | 3 | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| 40 | 13 | 14 | 15 | 16 | 4 | 2 | 1 | 4 |

You can use an update-with-join query:

```
update t set
t.c2 = a.c2,
t.c3 = b.c3,
t.c4 = c.c4,
t.c5 = c.c5
from t
join #temp as x on t.c1 = x.c1
join #temp as a on x.sk = a.k1
join #temp as b on x.sk = b.k2
join #temp as c on x.sk = c.k3
```

[DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/gpEx2z_-)

Comment: This seems pretty inefficient though, Would there be a more efficient way to do the same thing? Something that would work for 10k or 20k records.

Comment: @dizzyflames how often would you run the query? and how slow is it on 20k records?

Comment: It took about 40 minutes, I won't be running it that often. Maybe occasionally.

Comment: 40 minutes is too much agreed. I have changed the update query to use join syntax, when tested it gave a faaaaaar better execution plan. [Update] tested on 50k rows, updated in 2 seconds.

Comment: What about column 4 and 5? How would I modify the temporary table to shuffle these two columns in pairs?

Comment: They're shuffled in pairs. Look closely at the last two set clauses.

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be under the impression that all these values are unrelated; they aren't. `10` is related directly to `1`, `2`, `3` and `4`, and those values to each other as well. If you "shuffle" the value of `10` (in `c1`) then the values `1`, `2`, `3` and `4` go with it as they are a *single* row.

If you need to do this type of thing then firstly I'd suggest that all these values are on different rows and denote what "c" they belong to. So your data would look more like this:

| c | v |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 2 |
| 4 | 3 |
| 5 | 4 |
| 1 | 20 |
| 2 | 5 |
| 3 | 6 |
| 4 | 7 |
| 5 | 8 |

etc...

If your data looks like that, it's far easier to get the results you want. You can order you data on something "random" and the use conditional aggregation to get the values into their respective columns:

```sql
WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT *,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY C ORDER BY NEWID()) AS I
    FROM (VALUES(1,10),
                (2,1),
                (3,2),
                (4,3),
                (5,4),
                (1,20),
                (2,5),
                (3,6),
                (4,7),
                (5,8))YT(C,V))
SELECT MAX(CASE C WHEN 1 THEN V END) AS C1,
       MAX(CASE C WHEN 2 THEN V END) AS C2,
       MAX(CASE C WHEN 3 THEN V END) AS C3,
       MAX(CASE C WHEN 4 THEN V END) AS C4,
       MAX(CASE C WHEN 5 THEN V END) AS C5
FROM CTE
GROUP BY I;
```

If you "can't" get your data in a better format, you could unpivot it before you repivot it:

```
WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT V.C,
           V.V,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY V.C ORDER BY NEWID()) AS I
    FROM (VALUES(10, 1, 2, 3, 4),
                (20, 5, 6, 7, 8),
                (30, 9,10,11,12),
                (40,13,14,15,16))YT(C1,C2,C3,C4,C5)
         CROSS APPLY (VALUES(1,C1),
                            (2,C2),
                            (3,C3),
                            (4,C4),
                            (5,C5))V(C,V))
SELECT MAX(CASE C WHEN 1 THEN V END) AS C1,
       MAX(CASE C WHEN 2 THEN V END) AS C2,
       MAX(CASE C WHEN 3 THEN V END) AS C3,
       MAX(CASE C WHEN 4 THEN V END) AS C4,
       MAX(CASE C WHEN 5 THEN V END) AS C5
FROM CTE
GROUP BY I;
```